# SSRS 2008 R2 name field formatting it correctly

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-expression

In one of my reports a name field is bringing through people's names as:

john.smith

I have added =StrConv(Fields!name.value,vbProperCase). This now brings them through as John.Smith, which is better, but is there a way of removing the full stop between 'john' and 'smith'?

Any suggestions welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If possible adjust the output data in the query itself if that is not in your control then use following expression

```
 = Left(Fields!name.value, Len(Parameters!User.Value) - InStr(Parameters!User.Value, "."))+" "+ Right(Fields!name.value, Len(Parameters!User.Value) - InStr(Parameters!User.Value, "."))
```

Let me know in case of issue.

Comment: Accept it as answer if it helped you. So question can be closed.